# Cannot find method Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i have a function which should remove all editors for a selected range so that the owner is the only user in this range. In the most sheets it works but in some sheets it does not work and i have no idea why it does not work.

```
function setProtection(notation, sheet){
var protection = sheet.getRange(notation).protect().setDescription("Zugriff 
nicht erlaubt");
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
var ownerMail = me.getEmail();
var editors = protection.getEditors();
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  if(editors[i] != ownerMail){ 
     protection.removeEditors(editors[i]);
  }
}
protection.addEditor(me);
}
```

For me it seems like a bug.

That is error message:

Cannot find method removeEditors(User).

Thanks.

Comment: The error means that the variable `protection` could be null.  You need to check the value of `protection`  If you are not familiar with Apps Script troubleshooting, please take 5 minutes to read:  [Link to Apps Script Documentation - troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: Hello Sandy Good, protection can never be null because i set it everytime.  see: var protection = sheet.getRange(notation).protect().setDescription("Zugriff 
nicht erlaubt");

Comment: It doesn't matter what our logic is, or what either of us think or believe.  All that matters is what the actual value of `protection` is.  And the only way that you can know that is by printing the value to the logs.  `Logger.log('protection: ' + protection);` If you haven't done that, then you don't know for sure.

Comment: That is the result of the logger: [17-04-03 16:02:30:776 CEST] protection: Protection

Comment: I tried this:   Logger.log('protection: ' + JSON.stringify(protection));
it seems like you are right the protecion is a empty object("{}") but i do not understand this why it is allways empty for this sheet in other sheets it works.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is either.  All I know is that I would start checking every value.  That's what I do.  Check for what is getting passed in for `notation`.  Check for what is getting passed in for `sheet`.  I know it seems obvious what the values should be, but I spend a massive amount of time checking what I think should be the obvious, and that's the only way that I find the problem.

Comment: So i did check every Variable. I found that the protection is not empty because protection.getEditors(); shows me the editors.

Comment: If it is a bug, you can report it.  [Link to Apps Script Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)

Comment: Hello Sandy, i found the problem it is not a bug it is wrong documented. In the documentation and in the error message it says that removeEditors except a User but it is wrong removeEditors except an Array of User or Email. I found a function called removeEditor this except a User or a Email. I will report this! Thank you for you help.